# Do non-classical carbanions exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions, resonance

There are some non-classical carbocations, such as the [2-norbornyl cation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Norbornyl_cation), in which the positive charge is heavily delocalised. Have non-classical *carbanions* also been discovered? I have not seen any non-classical carbanions in books. If there are any non-classical carbanions, please provide some examples.

Comment: If an answer has helped solve your question, please consider upvoting and/or accepting one (by clicking on the tick next to the voting buttons). That's the Stack Exchange way of saying thank you! See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to the species mentioned in the answer above, I found another one in [Organic Chemistry by Morrison and Boyd(Seventh Edition)](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1YZkC04IkPIC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=nor-bornenone%20anion&source=bl&ots=iGdXClLLec&sig=cMsxDCkxFLT2vve6QiMZdqiUQMM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFpuCj3aTfAhVOWX0KHYNMCvMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=nor-bornenone%20anion&f=false)[image]

Comment: Please give me some references

Answer (score 24):

Interesting question. It is **much** less studied and reported on than the case of non-classical carbocations, but I did find a few papers. Brown and Occolowitz [(Ref.1)](https://doi.org/10.1039/C19650000376) reported that deuterated bicyclo[3.2.1]octa-2,6-diene **1b**, below, undergoes base-catalysed de-deuteration (potassium *tert*-butoxide in DMSO) to give **1a** *much* faster (*ca.* $3 \times 10^4$) than the bicyclo[3.2.1]octa-2-ene counterpart, *i.e.* **2b** $\rightarrow$ **2a**. They suggested this is evidence for the intermediacy of a 6π-electron, delocalised (non-classical) carbanion **3**.

[image: bicyclo[3.2.1]octenes]

Much more recently, Brown reviewed and provided additional DFT computational evidence for stabilisation and charge delocalisation in these species [(Ref.2)](https://doi.org/10.1071/CH14244).

**References:**

1. J. M. Brown, J. L. Occolowitz, “A non-classical carbanion,” *Chem. Commun. (London)* **1965**, *(16)*, 376-377 (https://doi.org/10.1039/C19650000376).
2. John M. Brown, “Origins of Stabilization and Evidence for Charge Delocalization in the Bicyclo[3.2.1]octadienyl Anion and Related Species,” *Australian Journal of Chemistry* **2014**, *67(9)*, 1296-1300 (https://doi.org/10.1071/CH14244).

Comment: Can one unselect an accepted answer??